# Using Cloud Firestore data in a Cloud Function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to create Cloud Functions that would fetch data from Cloud Firestore, and send a payment request to a payment gateway API using the values fetched from Cloud Firestore.

I can fetch the document I need from Firestore using this function:

```
exports.getData = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  const docRef = db.collection('requests').doc('vsFyJ5lisBgYNwQEzOLa');
  const getDoc = docRef.get()
    .then(doc => {
      if (!doc.exists) {
        console.log('No such document!');
        return res.send('Not Found')
      } 
        console.log(doc.data());
        return res.send(doc.data());
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('Error getting document', err);
      
    });
    
 });
```

However, this function only prints the document values; I need to use the values in another function like the one below:

```
exports.pay = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  var Iyzipay = require('iyzipay');
  const doc = db.collection('requests').doc('vsFyJ5lisBgYNwQEzOLa');
  const iyzipay = new Iyzipay({
    apiKey: 'apiKey',
    secretKey: 'secretKey',
      uri: 'https://sandbox-api.iyzipay.com'
  });
  var request = {
    locale: Iyzipay.LOCALE.TR,
    conversationId: '123456789',
    price: doc.price,
    paidPrice: doc.paidPrice,
    currency: Iyzipay.CURRENCY.TRY,
    installment: '1',
    basketId: 'B67832',
    paymentChannel: Iyzipay.PAYMENT_CHANNEL.WEB,
    paymentGroup: Iyzipay.PAYMENT_GROUP.PRODUCT,
    paymentCard: {
        cardHolderName: doc.cardHolderName,
        cardNumber: doc.cardNumber,
        expireMonth: doc.expireMonth,
        expireYear: doc.expireYear,
        cvc: doc.cvc,
        registerCard: '0'
    },
  };
iyzipay.payment.create(request, function (err, result) {
  console.log(err, result);
});
});
```

I tried to combine the functions like below:

```
exports.pay = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  var Iyzipay = require('iyzipay');
  const doc = db.collection('requests').doc('vsFyJ5lisBgYNwQEzOLa');
  const iyzipay = new Iyzipay({
    apiKey: 'sandbox-afXhZPW0MQlE4dCUUlHcEopnMBgXnAZI',
    secretKey: 'sandbox-wbwpzKIiplZxI3hh5ALI4FJyAcZKL6kq',
      uri: 'https://sandbox-api.iyzipay.com'
  });
  const docRef = db.collection('requests').doc('vsFyJ5lisBgYNwQEzOLa');
  const getDoc = docRef.get()
    .then(doc => {
      if (!doc.exists) {
        console.log('No such document!');
        return res.send('Not Found')
      } 
        console.log(doc.data());
        return res.send(doc.data());
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('Error getting document', err);
      
    });
  var request = {
    locale: Iyzipay.LOCALE.TR,
    conversationId: '123456789',
    price: '1',
    paidPrice: '1.2',
    currency: Iyzipay.CURRENCY.TRY,
    installment: '1',
    basketId: 'B67832',
    paymentChannel: Iyzipay.PAYMENT_CHANNEL.WEB,
    paymentGroup: Iyzipay.PAYMENT_GROUP.PRODUCT,
    paymentCard: {
        cardHolderName: doc.cardHolderName,
        cardNumber: doc.cardNumber,
        expireMonth: doc.expireMonth,
        expireYear: doc.expireYear,
        cvc: doc.cvc,
        registerCard: '0'
    }        
  };
iyzipay.payment.create(request, function (err, result) {
  console.log(err, result);
});
});
```

The payment processor returned an error while the Firestore query printed on the console like before.

I then tried was to try the call to payment processor with static values like below:

```
var request = {
    locale: Iyzipay.LOCALE.TR,
    conversationId: '123456789',
    price: '1',
    paidPrice: '1.2',
    currency: Iyzipay.CURRENCY.TRY,
    installment: '1',
    basketId: 'B67832',
    paymentChannel: Iyzipay.PAYMENT_CHANNEL.WEB,
    paymentGroup: Iyzipay.PAYMENT_GROUP.LISTING,
    paymentCard: {
        cardHolderName: 'John Doe',
        cardNumber: '5528790000000008',
        expireMonth: '12',
        expireYear: '2030',
        cvc: '123',
        registerCard: '0'
}
}
```

And the payment processor returned success, so there must be something wrong with the way I fetch or use the Firestore document values.

To test once more if it was indeed using Firestore values, I switched only one field to `cardNumber: doc.cardNumber`. The console returned:

```
✔  functions[pay]: http function initialized (http://localhost:5000/highmidlow1/us-central1/pay).
i  functions: Beginning execution of "pay"
⚠  External network resource requested!
   - URL: "https://sandbox-api.iyzipay.com/payment/auth"
 - Be careful, this may be a production service.
⚠  Google API requested!
   - URL: "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token"
   - Be careful, this may be a production service.
>  null {
>    status: 'failure',
>    errorCode: '12',
>    errorMessage: 'Invalid card number',
>    locale: 'tr',
>    systemTime: 1608311421424,
>    conversationId: '123456789'
>  }
>  {
>    expireYear: '2030',
>    paidPrice: 1.2,
>    cardNumber: '5528790000000008',
>    cvc: '123',
>    price: 1,
>    expireMonth: '12',  }
```

So how can I fetch a document from Firestore and use its values in a Cloud Function, like `price: doc.price`?

Comment: Seems like you just need to combine the query in the first function with the call to the payment processor in the second function.  What specifically are you having problems with about that?  Please edit the question to be clear.

Comment: Hi @DougStevenson, thanks for the quick reply. When I combine the two functions, the payment processor returns an error, while the Firestore query prints the values on the console. When I try the call to the payment processor with values like in price : '1' instead of price : doc.price, it returns success. Therefore, I thought that something must be wrong in the way I fetch and use the Firestore document values.

Comment: It's possible your Firestore has the doc.price as a *string*, and the payment processor needs it as a number.  Other common issues most often come down to some sort of formatting - "1", "$1", "1.00", 1, 1.00, "USD 1.00" are all possible ways the information might have been kept in the database.

Comment: If there is an error message, you should show that along with your debugging details so we can track what went wrong.

Comment: @LeadDreamer, thanks for the reply. I thought of that too, and I checked from the documentation of the processor whether the formats was correct. They seem to be correct, so I think it's about something else.

Comment: Why do you think it says "Invalid card number"?

Comment: @DougStevenson, when I ran the function with the cardNumber written as '5528790000000008' instead of doc.cardNumber, it worked. The card number is correct in Firestore too, as seen in the console. So my guess is right now, I can't use the data I fetched from Firestore. Maybe I need to return something like an object from the Firestore query to be able to use the data on the payment request. I could be completely wrong though.

Comment: Do not blindly trust the console - a lot of "type forcing" occurs to get a message to the console - I have *frequently* seen two values look them same on the browser console that were *not* === .  for example - what, in the firestore console, is the format of the cardNumber field?  Have you *checked*, in code, what format it is?  What format does the card processor require?

Comment: @LeadDreamer, the cardNumber field is a String, and the card processor require a String too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to move your request logic into the `.then(...)` block because right now it looks like you're trying to use the document result outside of the block where it is actually returned, which might be why you're getting an "invalid card number" error.

The Firestore API uses Promises for most/all fetch operations so you'll always need to wait for the result before using it.

```js
// ...
docRef.get().then(doc => {
    if (!doc.exists) {
        console.log('No such document!');
        return res.send('Not Found')
    }
    console.log(doc.data());
    res.send(doc.data());

    const request = { ... }
})
```

If you're using a node version that supports `async/await`, it might make it easier to spot these types of bugs.

```js
const doc = await docRef.get()
if (!doc.exists) {
    console.log('No such document!');
    return res.send('Not Found')
}
console.log(doc.data());
res.send(doc.data());

const request = { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I feel like this should work, but when I use async, I receive 'SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function'. To fix this, should I use something like async function pay() {} to make it an async function? If so, where should I start and end the async function?

Comment: I also fixed the code according to your first suggestion without the async, moved the request inside of the block where the document is returned, but it still gives the same invalid card number error.

Comment: Regarding your first question, yep you'll need to add `async` in front of the enclosing function any time you use `await`, which in your case is the anonymous callback that is passed to to cloud function api. So it'll be `functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => { ... })`. Functions marked with the `async` keyword are guaranteed to return a Promise no matter what, which can simplify result/error handling for the caller. As for start/end, I'd make the entire Cloud Function handler async and use `await` before every call that returns a promise

Comment: As for the failure, can you add the new failing code to your question?

Comment: I managed to solve it without the async, but I will surely implement it later. Your first suggestion was a big part of the solution, other than that I had to change the price: doc.price to price: doc.data(doc).price, and suddenly it worked! Thank you.